# Simpler proof that Square matrices have Two-Sided Inverses?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have seen some elaborate arguments to the effect that if an $ n \times n$ matrix is invertible it has 2-sided inverses. We show a 1-sided inverse implies matrix is ( represents) either injections or surjections (In the case of matrices, implies both.)

But this proof seems simpler:

Assume $AB=I_n  \Rightarrow $ A has a right inverse.

Then,

$ABA=I_nA=A \Rightarrow A(BA)=A $ $(*)$ Now

we know if $AB=I_n$ then both $A,B$ are invertible (e.g. $AB=I_n \Rightarrow \det(AB)=\det A \det B=\det I_n=1 $ so $\det A, \det B \neq 0$).

So,

multiplying both sides of $(*)$ by $A^{-1}$:

$A^{-1}(ABA)=(A^{-1}A)(BA)=BA=A^{-1}A=I_n$

Isn't this a simpler and valid proof? (Although I don't see how we are using any special properties of matrices)

Comment: What does it mean for a matrix to be invertible if not "has a left and right inverse", and therefore aren't you assuming what you want to prove?

Comment: Well,  we could have 1-sided invertibility, but you're right, but it's a bit confusing. If $DetADetB=1 $ doesn't this already prove 2-sided invertibility

Comment: In a sense yes but you're asking about something close to the foundations so you should make sure you aren't making a circular argument. Presumably this is one of the reasons the proof you saw is so long, they want to ensure they don't use things they haven't proved yet

Comment: So, if we know A had a left-inverse, we're done. If not, if we can only assume A has only a right inverse, then it is more difficult. Ok, will think it through some more. I never get right the conditions when a map has a right- or a left- inverse; I only know one is for onto the others is for 1-1, but never remember which is which  Thanks.

Comment: You say that if $AB=I$ then both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.  That is to say, if $B$ has a left inverse, then $B$ has a right inverse, which is what you want to prove.  Circular reasoning.